# How can I test for WP_Error?

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm writing tests using phpunit and WP_Mock for a WordPress plugin and I want to return a `WP_Error` if the method in my class isn't being called correctly (receiving all of the arguments it needs).

The standard way of doing this of course, would be to create and return a new `WP_Error` at that point - but as WordPress isn't loaded when I run the tests, the `WP_Error` class doesn't exist.

Other WordPress classes are being mocked and injected with Mockery, but this seems like overkill to test the `WP_Error` is being thrown; but I'm not seeing any other half-way sensible plan.

Is there a good way to mock the `WP_Error`?

Comment: _“but as Wordpress isn't yet loaded, that class doesn't exist”_ - well then what do you actually want to test at this point …?

Comment: The code I'm writing to extend it; everything else I'm mocking and injecting as a dependency, and that's an option I'm considering, but it feels like there ought to be a better solution.

Comment: I would start by using the [template_redirect action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) , "This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easiest way:** 
Just `include_once` the file with the definition for `WP_Error` (*wp-includes/class-wp-error.php*) when bootstrapping your tests. That way the class will be defined when you need to instantiate the class.

`WP_Error` doesn't have any other dependencies, so including it should be a big deal.

You are not not testing actual behaviour of the class, but only an object of that class is returned. So no need to mock anything if the proper definition exists.

**Better way:**
Use [WP-CLI](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/plugin-unit-tests/) to scaffold. Doing that you'd have access to wordpress functions and classes.

You'll need to install WP-CLI and have a working WP installation, with your plugin files in there.

First you'd need to do the plugin scaffolding. In your WP directory run

```
wp scaffold plugin-tests your-plugin
```

This will create a set of files in your plugin directory similar to this:

```
|-bin/
|----install-wp-tests.sh
|-tests/
|----bootstrap.php
|----test-sample.php
|-.travis.yml
|-phpcs.xml.dist
|-phpunit.xml.dist
|-your-plugin.php
```

You'll need to `cd` to your plugin directory, and from there run the test environment initialization:

```
bin/install-wp-tests.sh db_name db_user 'db_password' db_host wp_version
```

Parameters are self explanatory. wp_version can be `latest`. On this DB wp-cli will create a set of tables for testing, and it will create a WP installation in your /tmp directory, configured with the above values that will use in each time you run phpunit.

After that, it's a simple matter of calling `phpunit` and run your tests. You can use the `test-sample.php`as a starting point, or copy yours over there.

When running your tests this way, `WP_Error` will be defined, and you could easily test that your methods are returning it correctly.

Happy testing!

Comment: I can't use WP-CLI, as I'm using WP_Mock, and the two testing frameworks are mutually incompatible.

However, include-oncing seems to be the least bad solution available. So the bounty is yours!

Comment: WP-CLI is not a testing framework. But it is too bad WP_Mock is not compatible.

Comment: I mean the Wordpress testing framework which is installed via WP-CLI scaffold, per your answer.

Comment: Yeah,  understand. I'll have to read more about WP_Mock. But just including the file should get you out of this, since  you do not need to actually mock WP_Error.

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1:

Execute your tests after `plugins_loaded` action, like:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'your_func');
function your_func()
{
   ...
}
```

## Method 2:

Include once the `WP_error` class :

```
include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-wp-error.php');
...
your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning from T.Todua's answer, my `composer.json` looks like:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "cyruscollier/wordpress-develop": "dev-master",
        "10up/wp_mock": "0.4.2",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "*",
        "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "1.*"
    }
}
```

and in my `tests/UnitTest.php` `setUp()` method, I have:

```
$basedir = dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) );

require_once( $basedir . '/vendor/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php' );
```